# I have to reload factory setting every time I start. v2.90.1

Tags: navigation

Every time on start up I cannot navigate until I go to defaults and load factory settings.

Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Hi and welcome :) You probably have some add-on that is causing trouble for your startup .blend. So start from factory settings, and build your startup file again one add-on at a time.

Comment: I have never used add-ons and i uninstalled re-downloaded from blender then re-installed it.